# AppRequest Invalid access token with last Unity facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, sdk, unity-game-engine

I use a lot app requests in my Unity game, and this was working great. I have just updated to Sdk 6.0 and now when I send an app request I get the error:
{"error_code":"100","error_message":"Invalid+access_token"}

Other FB Api calls works fine, no problem while login and I could retrieve friends and stuff, so my Access Token seems to work. But not with FB.AppRequest apparently, and I don't see if I should pass it somewhere as a parameter.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Have resolved this issue. Im strugling with it.

Comment: I had to downgrad to an older version...

Answer (score 0):

Im leaving this answer for future searchs.

I`ve finally found out the problem. Searching through the FB class ive found that the method that was trowing such error has been changed to:

```
public static void AppRequest(
        string message,
        OGActionType actionType,
        string objectId,
        List<object> filters = null,
        string[] excludeIds = null,
        int? maxRecipients = null,
        string data = "",
        string title = "",
        FacebookDelegate callback = null)

public static void AppRequest(
        string message,
        string[] to = null,
        List<object> filters = null,
        string[] excludeIds = null,
        int? maxRecipients = null,
        string data = "",
        string title = "",
        FacebookDelegate callback = null)

public static void AppRequest(
        string message,
        OGActionType actionType,
        string objectId,
        string[] to,
        string data = "",
        string title = "",
        FacebookDelegate callback = null)
```

and i was missing some paramters that looks like facebook need to create a well formed url. Finally sending an apprequest like the next one, everything worked fine.

```
            FB.AppRequest(
                "Agregar amigos", 
                null,
                "",
                null,
                "{}", 
                "Amigo invisible", 
                appRequestCallback
                );
```